# How to add pagination to request in Python?

Tags: python, python-requests

I want to have a python request and add pagination, but for some reason it does not work,
this is my request. Does someone know how to add `'paging': '{"page":0,"size":100}'` corretly?  The following isn't working?
url = self.get_url_for_endpoint(Constants.PATH_STATISTICS_CUSTOMERS)

```
        payload = {}
        params = {
            'paging': '{"page":0,"size":100}'
        }
        headers = {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + self.access_token,
            'Cookie': 'JSESSIONID=AB52DV8260C*****************',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }
        r = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload, params=params)
```

This is working though via postman:

```
url + ?paging=%7B%22page%22:0,%22size%22:400%7D
```

So the endpoint has pagination!

Comment: So the requests library itself doesn't have the pagination built in. Is your API endpoint expecting `paging` as a parameter? If not you'll have to add logic to your endpoint that takes in paging information as a parameter. Can you share your what your API looks like?

Comment: what *does* work with this endpoint?   Can you get what you want with curl?  If you can make the request correctly with curl, you can do it with requests in python, but I suspect that as @Stoobish says your endpoint doesn't actually support pagination

Comment: Yes, the API endpoint is expecting the paging! I did put the postman request into the question.  I can get what I want with postman.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend using an object as your paging value in the params, instead break down your page and size into individual parameters, like `?page=0&size=100`.

But if you want to use an object, your params should be like this:

```
params = {
   "paging": {"page":0,"size":100}
}
```